# get activity from conductor controller

Tags: android, kotlin, conductor

I'm using `conductor` and I want to initialize `GoogleApiClient` in it.
As it is told in `conductor` doc, Conductor is made for replacing a `Fragment`. In `Fragment` I can easily get an `activity`. Is there a way do to that in `conductor`?

```
class SignInController : Controller(), GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private lateinit var mGoogleApiClient: GoogleApiClient
    private lateinit var mFirebaseAuth: FirebaseAuth

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup): View {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.controller_sign_in, container, false)
        val gso = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(view.context.getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .build()
        mGoogleApiClient = GoogleApiClient.Builder(view.context)
                .enableAutoManage(view.context /* I need an activity here */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build()

        mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

        return view
    }
}
```

I tried to use a `view.context` instead of `activity` but it doesn't work. It requires only `FragmentActivty`.
How to initialize `GoogleApiClient` inside conductor or to pass it there?
I wouldn't like to use `DI` here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution of this issue:
It's very simple. The view.context is already the MyActivity and I just need to cast it:

```
GoogleApiClient.Builder(view.context).enableAutoManage(view.context as MyActivity, this)
```

You also can get parent `activity` just by calling `getActivity()` in your `controller`